# WordPress 404 template overriding my .htaccess settings for 404 errors?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

On a subdirectory such as http://website.com/sub/index.html that has it's own .htaccess is still for some reason showing the 404 page I have for Wordpress which is on the directory above this one.

.htaccess for sub dir:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

.htaccess for main dir:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.net$
RewriteRule ^foghelper.php$ http://website.net/subdirone/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^foghelper.php$ http://website.net/subdirtwo/ [R=301,L]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE jNLK5d:REDIRECTID


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Links that were in the hta were censored in case your wondering.

**Edit:**

Upon adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?sub/` before `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` the error still seems to exist.

Comment: Have you seen this post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is being routed through wordpress so when a request for something like `/sub/no_file.html` and it doesn't exist, wordpress routes it through its `index.php` because it satisfies both the `!-f` and `!-d` conditions (not an existing file and not an existing directory). It then decides that it can't find the resource for `/sub/no_file.html` so it then displays its own 404 file.

If you want requests that go to /sub to bypass wordpress' routing so that if a file is requested in `/sub/` that doesn't exist, `/404.html` gets served, you can add this line right before `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
 in your wordpress rules so that they look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?sub/
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added that and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default .htaccess-file will already support the behaviour you want;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The magic is in the lines that start with RewriteCond. They instruct Apache to apply the rule RewriteRule . /index.php [L] (which means "any URL will go to index.php"), only when the URL is not an existing file !-f or existing directory !-d.

So this should work by default. The Wordpress rewrite rules do not apply when you try to visit an already existing file.

Comment: No, you see what I want to do is have sub directories, such sitename.com/subdir utilize its own 404 page. On my website certain web apps I have are on different directories, and they all have their own 404 that goes with the theme and such. Yet whenever I go to pages in these directories that do not exist, I am taken to the wordpress 404 error on the main directory.