# Non-Wordpress Directory not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

So, I have an install of Wordpress on my server, with WP default .htaccess rewrite rules, however, I have a directory that with a whole application on it, running off of a database that I need users to be able to access. My problem is that whenever I go to the directory, Wordpress reads it as being in the Wordpress database. How would I correct that?

Thanks!

Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this useful... [.htaccess & Wordpress: Exclude folder from RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule)

You need to exclude the folder from WordPress' Rewrite rules so WordPress doesn't intercept the folder. That linked answer should help.