# htaccess issue with website having WordPress directory containing Cakephp website

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am working on website having front website made with WordPress and a WordPress directory

contains a dashboard folder having a cakephp website. Everything is working perfectly on my

local system but when I migrated the whole website to online server I am unable to access

www.mywebsite.com/dashboard folder as I read here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40

this is a htaccess issue but I dont know htaccess coading at all so this link was confusing

to me if any one could explain me (in simple way) why this problem occurs? and how to

solve this problem? will be helpfull to me

my wordpress htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and cakephp htaccess which is in wordpress-install-directory/dashboard/cakephp-install

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you access the dashboard?

Comment: WordPress is giving 404 page not found error, if i delete htaccess file in WordPress install it starts working but I will have to use default Permalink Settings for WordPress otherwise WordPress pages and post don't work.

Comment: And the solution on the link you provide doesn't work? What about this one: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-error-from-the-dashboard-side

Comment: I have tried the solution on that link but I am not sure what I have done was correct as I don't know htaccess programming

Comment: If you delete the .htaccess then log in on using yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php and from here, go to Settings/Permalinks and click the Update Permalinks Structure button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just a case of changing your .htaccess to match the below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase  wordpress-install-directory/dashboard
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Doing the above will tell cake that the needed files are within instal-directory/dashboard.

You will also need to make the same change to webroot and app .htaccess

Comment: this was working perfectly but again have a API directory in cakephp install and again htaccess issue with api access .. so I have created a subdomain for dashboard and one for api.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If they are in different folders with independent .htaccess files, you might try to set the base directory for cakephp, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Could be dashboard or cakephp-install
    RewriteBase  /dashboard
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where should I add this htaccess code .. in wordpress roots htaccess file or in cakephp roots htaccess file

Comment: when I have added  it to above the wordpress htaccess giving Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

From a stackoverflow answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule/2350305#2350305
add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dashboard|dasboard/.*)$
```

before the last RewriteRule on your .htaccess file on wordpress directory and it should work.

Comment: Actually just to be safe you might also want to rename the folder as the /dashboard/ seems to already be taken from wordpress.