# .htaccess conflict

Tags: .htaccess, conflict, socialengine

This is my first question.
I have an wp-site on the root directory and it's own `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine off
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/katambi/public_html/php.ini
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

On another directory I've SocialEngine network site. It also has `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Problem: when i enter to package and plugins page it display 404 error. =(

When i delete code between

```
# BEGIN WordPress
```

and

```
# END WordPress
```

wp-site down but social network runs correct.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: ¿How is the directory structure, where is WP, where the "social" application, where are the .htccess files...? Supply complete information, please.

Comment: root/.htaccess   /*wp's htaccess*/                       
root/socialengine folder/.htacess  /*social's htaccess*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` is redirecting all request to root directory's index.php. You need to make sure that requests to SocialEngine's directory is not being redirected. So you can try this solution- [.htaccess & Wordpress: Exclude folder from RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule)

Comment: How can check the SocialEngine install redirects?
I think that WP .htaccess file write it's rule under Social's .htaccess. 
It's important that i have 404 error only on "Install" folder.
Other parts of Social are run ok.

Comment: You can write a rule for SocialEngine install folder in SocialEngine's .htaccess file.

Comment: And question for $million: What shall i write? :)