# Unable to access controllers of codeigniter which is installed under a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Wordpress site. So all i wish is to fetch the information from those database tables and create my own custom **API's**. For that i opted CodeIgniter Framework.

**The file directory system looks like this in my FTP**
[image]

My codeigniter files are placed in **apps** folder

[image]

> The problem is the pages are not loading, It always returns 404 Error
>   or No Input file specified/found etc.

I tried changing **.htaccess** file but no luck.

But if i specify

> applications/apps

i.e controller/method in default_url in **routes.php** it works fine.

and if i click on the Hyperlink, i am  trying to load another view or call another View(a web page) but this returns 404 error page not found.

What might be the reason behind this.

Comment: did you edit the wordpress .htaccess as well? Both apps use `mod_rewrite` which would block you from using CI in a subfolder

Comment: NO, actually i was bit scared that if i change .htaccess of wordpress something might go wrong.

Comment: umm ok... well being scared is no way to program then...

Comment: :-) Nice. I will take backup and try. On what basis .htaccess file to be edited? Can you please suggest!

Comment: searching helps => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule