# How to install a 2nd Wordpress site on subdir

Tags: wordpress

I have to move a WP site to another domain where I already have WP running in the root.
Because this is a temporary solution, I don't want to change the existing WP installation to multisite. I want to keep both sites and DBs separated as I'll move the site back later.
So, in a nutshell, I want to move site.com/wpsubdir/ to site-running-wp.com/wpsubdir/

I've tried a dozen different things, mostly around excluding that subdir from the root's rewrite rules but nothing works. The root's WP site still takes over and shows a 404 for every page, including static html ones.

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess & Wordpress: Exclude folder from RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks @vard. Before posting I tried everything there with no success whatsoever

Comment: Could you share the content of your htaccess in your question?

Comment: you need to modify your apache or nginx set up (presumably you are using one of the two), there are loads of tutorials if you google apache subomain set up etc. But if you have cpanel or similiar google using that instead...