# excluding file in wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress

I my wordpress directory I have a file called 'werk'.
I want this file ignored by wordpress, this is how it looks:
[image]

So there is a file werk that I dont want to be interacting with the wordpress files.

I know it has something to do with the .htaccess This is how my .htaccess looks:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)/(.*).htm$ index.php?smsite=$1&smid=$3&smtemp=$2 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: i think you must be looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule
hope that helps!

Comment: @RohitS I have been thru that question but it is not working for me.