# Deploying Laravel on a shared hosting sub-directory

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy laravel 5.5 inside a WordPress sub-directory on a shared hosting. I tried too many suggestions from google but I still can't make it work. It always returns a 404 error. WordPress is installed inside `/public_html`
and I need to install Laravel on `/public_html/my-laravel-app`
Here's what my `.htaccess` files look:

**/public_html/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# protect wpconfig.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off
```

**/public_html/my-laravel-app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /my-laravel-app/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /my-laravel-app/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/public_html/my-laravel-app/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**/public_html/my-laravel-app/public/index.php (some part of index.php)**

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file ?!

Comment: @dexterb Make sure, Is laravel working on sheared hosting, If yes then go with sub-domain. I think it's not working on sheared hosting.

Comment: So when you access  /my-laravel-app/public/index.php on your shared hosting, which error does it give you? When you look in the laravel.log, which errors do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to update this question, but I already solved this problem.
**It's not actually about WordPress' .htaccess, I get rid of my custom .htaccess settings**.
What I did was, create a new folder on `public_html/laravel-app` then inside my `laravel-app`,
this is where I cloned the repo, so it became, `public_html/laravel-app/my-app`
then, I copied the files(except the folders) inside `my-app/public` directory and moved it to `laravel-app/`.

```
$ cd /public_html/laravel-app
$ cp -a my-app/public/*.* ./
```

Then I created a symbolic link for the directories inside `my-app/public` by running

```
$ ln -sf my-app/public/*/ ./
```

And lastly, I modified the `public_html/laravel-app/index.php`
on line 22 and line 36,

```
require __DIR__.'/my-app/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/my-app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then it's done.

Comment: i did exactly what you wrote, but still it is showing me 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: can you write down the symbolic path command exactly as you did

Comment: In my case I did, `ln -sf /public_html/laravel-app/my-app/public/*/ /public_html/laravel-app/`
to only symlink the directories.
I updated the symlink command above.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't work on subfolders out of the box. You will need to tweak some files in order to get it to work. Have a look at the following article on [laravel-news.com](https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install)

My suggestion would be to re-consider your approach and see if there's a different way to achieve your goal that doesn't require a subfolder.

Edit:

I'd like to include more steps from the article just in case it gets removed in the future but it's just too many steps.

Comment: I think it's a bit different issue from the article. I'm having trouble with the WordPress .htaccess as it keeps redirecting my subfolder to a 404. :((

Comment: hey @dexterb is the 404 coming from WP or Laravel?

Comment: 404 is coming from WP

Comment: try excluding the laravel subdirectory from WP's .htaccess, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule

Comment: Actually laravel work wherever you put it on. What if you have a VPS where you have a bounch of sites? That sites are "subfolders" and you deploy laravel inside of them, so, that is why i think your logic is not good at all

Comment: @FernandoTorres: nope, I think you are getting confused. When you say "a bunch of sites", sure, that will work if every site is setup to have the document root at the site folder level. That's very different from having laravel in the sub folder of a website though: that's definitely not going to work out of the box.