# Deploy Laravel project on subfolder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel 5.5 project on my web hosting ( PHP version 7.1.xx ).
I have multiple hosting on the same server so when I connect using FTP that what I have:

```
-WEBSITE NUMBER 1
 -- WordPress files

-WEBSITE NUMBER 2
-- WordPress files 

-WEBSITE NUMBER 3
-- WordPress files
```

Now what I want is a subfolder of www.WEBSITENUMBER3.com/app/  running laravel.
So I did 2 folders at the same level:

```
 -WEBSITE NUMBER 1
 -- WordPress files

-WEBSITE NUMBER 2
-- WordPress files 

-WEBSITE NUMBER 3
-- WordPress files
-- app 
-- laravelApp
```

Inside of **app** folder I put the files of the Public directory of Laravel, and in the **laravelApp** folder I put all my laravel project ( except public folder )
Now the problem is that when I visit **www.WEBSITENUMBER3.com/app/** all the links are broken, bootstrap doesn't get load because he tries to load :

> www.WEBSITENUMBER3.com/bootstrap
>
> instead of www.WEBSITENUMBER3.com/app/bootstrap

so all the things of my Application.
So is there a way to change the root where laravel works?
I found impossible and wrong change all links in Laravel manually to make them absolutely I want to keep them relative.

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` file inside your public folder? Are the paths to the bootstrap files correct?

Answer (score -2):

You should set the right path four your app in the `.env` file, in the root folder.

The `APP_URL` line should be set like this:

`APP_URL=www.WEBSITENUMBER3.com/app/`

After changing the `.env`, you need to restart the webserver. The additional steps depend on your webserver.

Comment: Ok i edit the .env, but nothing seems change, i think i have to do a command like "artisan update" or something like that, right? Actually in my webhosting i dont have a console to use, so what the best way to update changes?

Comment: What is your web hosting?

Comment: Well there is not possible to restart the server, Aruba.it does only "manually restart", another way?

Comment: I think you can always ask for a restart from the support. Alternatively, you can deploy the app again, or delete the `.env` and upload again a bit later.

Comment: By the way, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890085/deploying-laravel-on-a-shared-hosting-sub-directory?rq=1

Comment: Yes i can ask, but it takes a long time, 1/2 days ... And if need another update? I always ask for a manual reboot? Welcome in 1990 .

Comment: This only applies for changes in hidden files.

Comment: Im gonna try to delete env and re upload it

Comment: Could you get it sorted?

Comment: I tried updating .env file. but not working.