# Host Laravel website inside subdirectory of another laravel website is possible

Tags: php, laravel, web, hosting

I need to host a laravel website in sub directory of parent laravel website. I already placed the sub laravel app inside parent folder That is I need a URL of new site Like

```
http://FirtsLaravelApp/SecondLarevelApp
```

I already see the similar questions. But not found any effective solution for me. Is there any solution to solve my problems. Any solution is much appreciable

Thanks....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Laravel on a shared hosting sub-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890085/deploying-laravel-on-a-shared-hosting-sub-directory)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can hit your URL with `/public` for the case of multiple website of Laravel.

```
http://FirtsLaravelApp/SecondLarevelApp/public
```

or you can create subdomain and host multiple project separately on single CPanel for the better use.

Comment: But the url you mentioned http://FirtsLaravelApp/SecondLarevelApp/public is show the 404 page. That is url not found. Have any more options.....???