# wordpress htaccess file causes new files and folders to show 404 error?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following code in my htaccess file which is related to wordpress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I created a new folder called `test` and when I try to access it from the browser, it shows a 404 error.

when I remove the code above from the htaccess file, I can access the new folder but the rest of the wordpress site breaks up. so I can't get rid of this code at all.

I tried adding this to the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
```

so it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With no result and I still see the 404 error.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

I've tried many ways including this and still nothing works!!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(test) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you mean you transfered a fiel

Comment: @VasimVanzara, I haven't moved or transferred anything! I simply created a folder directly from the cPanel. I also created test files (test.php and test.html) and I still get the 404 error when I try to access them form the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**How to move WordPress installation to sub folder**

Move wp-*, index.php, .htaccess to your new wordpress folder
Edit wordpress/.htaccess:

Find this line: RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Make it: RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
Create a new file in /path/to/www called .htaccess then add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/wordpress/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Another way to do move all thing in sub directory**

- rename htaccess to backhtaccess.
- Login to admin
- Go settings -> permalinks-> save changes. All done.

**=========================UPDATED ANSWER==============================**

Add this line in your themes functions.php:

```
include(ABSPATH . 'custom.php');
```

Explanation:

Your wp-config.php should contain the following code (near the bottom of the page):

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

They are saving the path to the wordpress installation to ABSPATH.

It will be something like "/var/www/foo/" or similar. So you can concat the ABSPATH with path to your file. If for example, your php file is located inside some folder like this "example.com/somefolder/custom.php" you would use

```
include(ABSPATH . 'somefolder/custom.php');
```

Hope this helps!

**=======================Answer 3======================**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test/.*)$ 
</IfModule>
```

You can whitelist a folde using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|test/.*)$
```

Reference link :

[.htaccess & Wordpress: Exclude folder from RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule)

Comment: Referance : https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: I haven't moved or transferred anything! I simply created a folder directly from the cPanel. I also created test files (test.php and test.html) and I still get the 404 error when I try to access them form the browser.

Comment: You mean public_html/test/test.html ?

Comment: public_html/test/test.php, public_html/test/test.html, public_html/test, public_html/test.html, public_html/test.php all give me 404 error.

Comment: may I have url please

Comment: the url is only showing a 404 error. unfortunately I cannot share the URL in the public forum.

Comment: Tried your updated suggestion and it didn't work! This issue is purely related to that part of the htaccess code I posted in my question because as I said, when I RMEOVE IT, I can access the files/folders that I created. I doubt you fully understood the question.

Comment: The last code you posted causes other pages to break and they all show: Not Found error.

Comment: can we have screenshare?

Comment: did you see referance link